# Azure IOT-Edge - Logs to Azure Monitor

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

Is there a supported/standard way to send container logs (info, errors etc.) to Azure Monitor, as there is for metrics with the Metrics collector module in Azure IoT Edge?

I know about this solution, but is there a supported/standard way to solve this?
https://github.com/veyalla/logspout-loganalytics

/Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [IoT ELMS](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iotedge-logging-and-monitoring-solution), which is mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-troubleshoot-monitoring-and-faq?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034&view=iotedge-1.4&pivots=metrics-collection#how-do-i-collect-logs-along-with-metrics). It leverages an OpenTelemetry module that uploads logs to Log Analytics. It also describes a second way of doing it, which utilizes a timed Azure Function to send Direct Methods to the device, asking for the logs and then uploading them to Log Analytics.

But the repository you linked is by Venkat Yalla; his team is responsible for the Metrics collector, so I'd say that module is as close to standard as it'll get.

Comment: The logspout-loganalytics has been archived on the day you posted this answer and it's also linking to IoT ELMS, which makes that the only semi-official solution (semi-official because it's in Azure-Samples)